# Can't test app on my Samsung Galaxy S+ Xamarin Deployment failed because of an internal error: Permission denied

Tags: android, deployment, xamarin, device

I have weird problem. I can't test my app on my real device (Samsung Galaxy S Plus). I am coding Android App in Xamarin.
I was trying to change different options with using shared Mono runtime, and fast deployment, but it didn't work :(
I get such logs during building:

```
// ---------- (Mono runtime unchecked) -------------
Detecting installed packages

Waiting for packaging to complete

Installing application on device

Deployment failed because of an internal error: Permission denied

Deployment failed. Internal error.
```

and

```
// ---------- (Mono runtime checked) -------------
Detecting installed packages

Installing shared runtime

Deployment failed because of an internal error: Permission denied

Deployment failed. Internal error.
```

I have no idea how to solve it. Releasing app to .apk works normally, but it's so uncomfortable to Publish Android Application, then copy .apk to the phone, install it and test...

Comment: Build or Release? Have you already changed the build output for more detailed messages? Perhaps you'll receive usefull information like that.

Comment: Removing the application from your device may help. I faced an issue like that before and removing the application before deploying it solved it for me.

Comment: i've removed app before trying. i've plugged in my friend's phone - sony erikson, and it normally deploys. there are problems with my phone? not with xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on a real device in the past (Samsung Galaxy S5).  From the research I did before on this issue, the recommended approach was to just *disable* **'Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)'** in the **project properties**, in **Android Options**, in the **Packaging** tab.  This worked for me to get around the issue and at least you can debug within **Visual Studio**.

I know this is not an ideal solution as deployments will take longer, but at least you can test and debug on a real device which was more important to me.  It appeared from previous research on this that this issue affects some *Samsung* devices.

Comment: it doesn't work, i tried to disable using fast demployment and it didn't help :(

Comment: Do you have the phone configured for developer use in the settings on the device?

Comment: yes, of course, phone is visible in xamarin, and it starts deploying but after a while it fails

Comment: Can you check your Android Options in Visual Studio again.  The following is my configuration:- **Packaging Tab** : 'Use Shared Runtime' is *only* checked.  **Linker** : 'None' is selected.  **Advanced Tab** : The three checkboxes at the top is checked; 'Java Max Heap Size' is at '1G'.

Comment: Also on your phone go into **Settings** --> **Developer Options** --> **USB Debugging** should be checked.

Comment: @Pete thanks this solved my issue with Samsung Duos on 4.2.2